# NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:9000/upload.php - trying to make Angular work with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, node.js, post

I am trying to implement an angular directive for uploading files - [here](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/tree/master/examples/simple) is the directive.

Everything seems to be working fine except I am getting this error:

`NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:9000/upload.php`

I am using the same `upload.php` file as is in the examples folder of the directive's github repo.

I have tried a few things - including using relative and absolute paths...as well as trying a few different places to put `upload.php`. I realize that Apache handles php stuff so I tried putting `upload.php` in the folder that Apache knows to look for php files on my computer (when it needs to execute them in the browser) - and then referenced that location absolutely in the angular files - but that didn't seem to work either. I also tried using `grunt-php` - not sure if I set that up correctly but that didn't seem to do anything either.

More specifically - the error occurs on a `POST` call, I have found a few things saying that Angular with PHP and post calls can be tricky but I have not been able to put the pieces together myself.

Here is the code in the angular controller that references `upload.php`:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
  url: 'upload.php'
});
```

I have the upload.php file in the same folder as the controller.

How can I make angular correctly detect `upload.php`?

**UPDATE**

I was using the yeoman `angular-fullstack` generator and I found another generator (`angular-php`) which is basically the same thing with built in functionality for PHP. I tried using it and I am still getting the same problem...now I have `upload.php` in the `api` folder of the seed (where I think it is supposed to go) - you can find the seed [here](https://github.com/amercier/generator-angular-php). I am still getting the same error however...but I think I should probably use the `angular-php` seed instead of the `angular-fullstack` seed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you open URL http://localhost:9000/upload.php in browser does it work?

Comment: @KostyaShkryob good idea - might be helpful to see if that is the case...I'm guessing it might...if it doesn't it might be because `upload.php` isn't in the folder that apache points to...the problem is that the file cannot be found though so i'm not sure if it will be helpful to know whether or not the php file is functioning...I'll see what happens though - not on my computer with files right now...will try and get back to you.

Comment: @KostyaShkryob Also - I read that I don't need to use php do do what the php file is doing (and it might be better for me to write the same functionality with javascript as I am using js frameworks)...I think I might try this and try avoiding having to incorporate php altogether...so if you can look at the code in upload.php and help me understand how to write something that could be used in the same way with js that would be cool - I will also probably be able to figure it out myself.