# Angular php file not found

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to receive date and send it to the php file

```
$http.post('views/php.php', {
  item: $scope.email
})
.success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

but console log says

> POST http://localhost:9000/views/php.php 404 (Not Found)

However if I go the link it shows and starts downloading.

Why does this happen?

Comment: because that file is not available there, as 404 does mean that

Comment: @pankajparkar it is available there but gives me error not found

Comment: @pankajparkar I searched I found this people have the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934635/networkerror-404-not-found-http-localhost9000-upload-php-trying-to-make

Comment: What are the contents of the file? Is the php code in the file throwing the error, perhaps?

Comment: @Erik I copyed and pasted code actually? is it gives errors like not found if there something wrong? I don't know too much about php

Comment: If you go to the link what exactly is downloading ? The php file ? If so, then you server may not be correctly configured.

Comment: POST (what you are doing in angular) is different form GET (clicking on the link)

Answer (score 1):

You are not running it on apache that's why its downloading! You are running it on npm server WhIch  cannot interpret PHP. Run it from xampp's it should work fine .